# Doxygen not running when started with the Windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, task, doxygen, scheduler

I've started using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) to document my team's project source code (we have C#, Objective-C, and Android/Java projects). I wrote up a Windows batch script which checks out the latest trunk versions of each project and uses the command-line Doxygen to generate HTML documentation sites and publish to a directory on the local file system which IIS 7 already hosts. This batch script works perfectly and does everything it needs to, though it takes 10 - 20 minutes to run completely.

Now I'm trying to automate the process so that it will run at the end of every day. I added a scheduled task which simply runs the batch script. Every part of the script seems to work except for the Doxygen part. I can log into the machine and watch the file system and see that working copies are being checked out with no problem and the cleanup stuff works. However it never generates the Doxygen HTML output. The output/target directories Doxygen is configured to use will stay empty every time. I'm finding no error messages of any kind (in Scheduled Tasks and eventvwr). It doesn't work whether I let the task scheduler start it on its own or I tell it to run the task now. As said earlier, I can double-click the batch file and run it normally and everything works fine that way.

The process is done on our development server, it's an older Dell workstation running Windows Vista Business 32-bit. I have the scheduled task running on the "System" account though I have also tried "Local Service" and my own Active Directory domain account (which is an administrator on this server) and it still doesn't work.

Has anyone else successfully used the task scheduler to automate Doxygen? I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. What should I look for next?

I can post slightly anonymized versions of my batch file and Doxygen config files if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your batch file, try adding redirection of the doxygen output to a log file. Then run it through the scheduler and see what output was generated. If doxygen encounters an error when run that way you should see it in the log file.

```
doxygen doxyfile > doxygen.log 2>&1
```

Also make sure that your bat file runs correctly, even if invoked from another directory than the one where the doxygen stuff resides. When run through the task scheduler, I think that the current directory will be c:\windows\system32, so try this:

```
c:\windows\system32>c:\path\to\batchfile\mybatch.bat
```

If that gives path errors you have to fix them.

Comment: I added what you suggested and it created the doxygen.log file however it was empty once the task finished. I don't think the working directory matters because I used absolute file paths on everything, but I ran it manually in CMD from a different working directory and it worked fine. Now I added a > batchLog.log to the scheduled task's parameters and I'll take a look at that.

Comment: My example just redirected the normal output, error output was still lost. See my update above with `2>&1` added. That will include stderr output in the log too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it working! The issue is that doxygen's install path is part of my PATH when I'm logged in but apparently is not part of PATH in the task scheduler, so it was failing to find the program. I replaced it in my batch with the full path to doxygen.exe and it works now.